# Prove that a Modified Cantor Distribution is Atomic.

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory, game-theory, lebesgue-measure

Consider a measurable space $\{\mathcal{I},\mathcal{B}\}$, where $\mathcal{I} = [0,1]$ and $\mathcal{B}$ are the Borel sets on $\mathcal{I}$. And also, denote $\mathcal{C}$ as the cantor set on $\mathcal{I}$.

Define an order $\mathcal{R}$ on $\mathcal{I}$ as: if both $s,t$ lie in $\mathcal{C}$, or both $s,t$ lie in the complement of $\mathcal{C}$, then $s\mathcal{R}t$ iff $s>t$; if $t \in \mathcal{C}$, while $s$ not, then $s\mathcal{R}t$. And define initial segment as $I(s,\mathcal{R})=\{t:s\mathcal{R}t\}$.

Now, define a set function $v=f\circ\lambda$, where $f$ is canter function, and $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure function.

Question, is there a measure function $\varphi^{\mathcal{R}}v$ on measurable space $\{\mathcal{I},\mathcal{B}\}$, which is induced by $\varphi^{\mathcal{R}}v(I(s,\mathcal{R})) = v(I(s,\mathcal{R})), \forall s \in \mathcal{I}$? If there is, is it atomic?

This is a statement on Page 95 of *"Values of Non-Atomic Games 1972 by Aumann and Shapley"*. Could anyone can explain in detail? Thank you.

P.S. Measure function $\varphi^{\mathcal{R}}v$ is Non-Atomic on $\{\mathcal{I},\mathcal{B}\}$ iff $\forall S \in \mathcal{B}$, if $\varphi^{\mathcal{R}}v(S)>0$, then there must exist $T \in \mathcal{B}, T \subset S$ and $\varphi^{\mathcal{R}}v(T)>0$. And the Cantor function is exactly Devils Staircase function.

Comment: can you please clarify what atomic means and also is the cantor function you are talking about is it the same Devils Staircase function?

Comment: Yes, I have added these things. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how such a measure (call it $\mu$ for brevity)  could exist. The definition of order implies  that $I(1,\mathcal R)$ is   precisely $C\setminus \{0\}$. Since $\lambda(C)=0$, we must have $\mu(C\setminus \{1\})=0$. Let $\alpha=\mu(\{1\}) = \mu(C)$.

Next, for $s\notin C$ the set $I(s,\mathcal R)$ is the union of $C$  and the interval $[0,s)$. Therefore, $\mu([0,s))=f(s)  - \alpha$. If $\alpha>0$ than we can pick $s\notin C$ such that $f(s)<\alpha/2$, and arrive at a contradiction: $\mu([0,s))<0$. Thus, $\alpha=0$.

For all $s\notin C$ we have $\mu([0,s))=f(s)$. Also, $f$ is constant on every interval in the complement of $C$. Therefore, each such interval has zero $\mu$-measure. So the measure is just zero, which obviously does not work.

Comment: Thank you. But I think $s\searrow 0$ part has a problem. We can't let $s$ approach to $0$ without passing through cantor set.

Comment: @thisismuchhealthier.Maybe I misunderstood what you mean. You mean "each such interval ($[0,s),\forall s\in [0,1]$?)has zero $\mu$-measure", how does this come from?

Comment: @ReasoningtheReasons Let $I$ be an interval in the complement of $C$. Since $\mu([0,s))=f(s)-\alpha$, and $f$ is constant on $C$,  it follows that $\mu([0,s))$ has the same value for all $s\in I$. Hence $\mu(I)=0$.

Comment: That's why I am confused. What I understand is that $f$ is constant on the connected part of the complement of $\mathcal{C}$, but if $t,s$ lies in the complement of $\mathcal{C}$ but does not lie in the connected part, then $f(s)\neq f(t)$. This is what I mean "We can't let s approach to 0 without passing through cantor set". For example, $t=\frac{1}{6},s=\frac{1}{2}$, then $f(t) = \frac{1}{4},f(s)=\frac{1}{2}$, do I understand correctly?

Comment: @ReasoningtheReasons I rewrote the paragraph to make it clearer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Sorry, I still can't catch you very much. I understand $\alpha = 0$, which is also very intuitive. What is confusing to me is that in my opinion,  $f$ is constant on the connected part of the complement of $\mathcal{C}$, so we can't get that "each such interval has zero μ-measure".

Comment: @ReasoningtheReasons My [earlier comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/856123/prove-that-a-modified-cantor-distribution-is-atomic/856428?noredirect=1#comment1767100_856428) was about this point. Is there something unclear in it? Consider that the measure of an open interval is the supremum of the measures of its closed subintervals.

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand. For me, I admit that $\mu$ has value 0 for each connected part of the complement of $\mathcal{C}$, for example $(\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3})$; however, it's not true if the set is not like this, for example $(\frac{1}{6},\frac{1}{2})$. Can you explain in detail for the question started by "That's why I am confused...". Thank you very much, and your help is well appreciated.

Comment: @ReasoningtheReasons The complement of $C$ is the countable union of open intervals. Measures are countably additive.

Comment: It seems that I understand what you mean now. Do you mean that we can decompose the whole $\mathcal{I}$ into $\mathcal{C}$ and open sets $\{O_n:n \in \mathbb{N}\}$left during the construction of Cantor set. We can have that $\varphi^{\mathcal{R}}v(\mathcal{C}) = 0$ and for each open set $O \in \{O_n:n \in \mathbb{N}\}$, we also have $\varphi^{\mathcal{R}}v(O) = 0$. Then we have that for each set $S$ in $\mathcal{B}$, we can decompose it into $S\cap\mathcal{C}$ and $\{S\cap O_n:n \in \mathbb{N}\}$, then we have it's 0 $\mu$-measure? Thank you very much.

Comment: @ReasoningtheReasons Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: OK, thank you very much for your great help and patience.